# How to override firefox default styles like chrome?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox

Is there any method to override the default styles of Firefox with the default styles of Chrome?

Comment: You're asking about *default* styles, but then you are talking about a website you built, which would indicate you need to adjust *your* styles to work in both browsers equally well. Can you clarify what you're question is? Try adding a [mcve] of your website's code to the question to make it easier to understand.

Comment: Yes, I should have done that.. But, I created just by seeing chrome. So, there are some differences in firefox. I know I could change to my custom styles. Here, what I am saying is.. why don't I change firefox to chrome and then I don't have to change code specifically to firefox..

Comment: What you're saying is still completely unclear. Do you want to change the browser's default styles? Or do you want a specific website to look and work exactly the same between two browsers? If the latter, then you **must** include a [mcve] in your question because it's *your* code that needs adjusting.

Comment: No, I am saying the first one. I want to change the browser's default styles... Now, to be specific I want to default styles of chrome to be applied to every other browsers.

Comment: OK, then there's no reason to mention your website because your website's styles will override any browser's default styles.

Answer (score 0):

there is a way for override firefox default property ,
you can follow this github to get some default property of browsers 
and you can override chrome default style with the webkit --webkit
and mozila provide it with --moz 
follow link
https://github.com/sw4/revert.css
and override firefox style

Comment: Can you explain a bit. As, github does barely have any explanation and how to use?

Answer (score 0):

i dont know on firefox browser how can exact do this but i know you can override chrome style with some override on chrome kit on firefox is the sameway with overriding moz attribute create a simple css file link it to your html then add attribute you need to override or change like that `

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    color : "red"!important
    }
```

`for chrome styles and something same for firefox`

```
scrollbar {
/*  clear useragent default style*/
   -moz-appearance: none !important;
}
/* buttons at two ends */
scrollbarbutton {
   -moz-appearance: none !important;
}
/* the sliding part*/
thumb{
   -moz-appearance: none !important;
}
scrollcorner {
   -moz-appearance: none !important;
   resize:both;
}
```

` but my code is not exact true need to more explain about "-moz-appearance"